# Swift- Pushing notifications at a user selected time

Tags: swift, date, ios8, notifications, picker

How can I make a user choose a time by using a date picker and then send the user a local notification?

Comment: This question is way, way, *way* too broad for Stack Overflow's format.  You're trying to [eat an elephant](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/).  You have at least two problems here.  How can I let the user pick a datetime using a date picker and save it as a date object?  How can I send a local notification at a specific date time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple code to schedule a local notification in swift:

```
let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let fireDateOfNotification: NSDate = //The date which was picked from the picker

var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
notification.alertBody = "ALERT STRING"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification
notification.userInfo = ["UUID": "NotificationID"] //id for the local notification in case you want to cancel it

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

and if you want to cancel a local notification you should use the following  function:

```
func cancelLocalNotificationsWithUUID(uuid: Int) {
        for item in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications {
            let notification = item as! UILocalNotification
            if let notificationUUID = notification.userInfo?["UUID"] as? Int {

                if notificationUUID == uuid {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.